# QLineEdit::maxLength support for Android

Tags: android, qt

I'm deploying a Qt application under Android. When a `QLineEdit` length is limited (using `setMaxLength`), the Android virutal keyboard lets me enter more characters than allowed and later the `QlineEdit` content is truncated when virtual keyboard is closed.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLineEdit>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    QApplication app( argc, argv );    

    QMainWindow wnd;

    QLineEdit edit( &wnd );
    edit.setMaxLength( 10 );
    wnd.setCentralWidget( &edit );

    wnd.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Is there any way to have this limit be handled by the virtual keyboard not to let user enter more characters than allowed?

Note: Created qt bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-61940

Answer (score -1):

There are different alternatives, the first one its using the [QLineEdit::setMaxLength](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlineedit.htmlYou) function. According to the official documentation:

> This property holds the maximum permitted length of the text. If the
>   text is too long, it is truncated at the limit.

If you have problems with the Android Keyboard, then an alternative, you can set the max allowed size by using a [QValidator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qvalidator.html) with a given [QRegExp](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexp.html). For your purpose a good one could be:

```
/^(?=.{3,16}$)[a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:_[a-z0-9]+)*$/
```

Or an easiest one:

```
^\s*([^\s]\s*){0,400}$
```

Where the value {0, 400}  defines the maximum allowed size of your string. Example:

```
QRegExp regexp("^\s*([^\s]\s*){0,400}$");
QRegExpValidator *validator = new QRegExpValidator(regexp, this);
lineEdit->setValidator(validator);
```

The last one, try to avoid it, just handle the [textChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#text-prop) signal and limit the string manually.

Comment: I doubt this will be handled by Android virtual keyboard. It will be the same behaviour, user will be allowed to enter whatever he wants and then content will be modified upon validation...

Comment: This does not prevent user from entering more characters than expected under Android. It ends up with the same behaviour as `setMaxLength`